# connecting my vb.net app to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection

guys i'm trying to develop an app (using vb.net & sql database) ,managing my database using PhpMyAdmin ,so the problem is , when executing my app , it shows nothing :/ , i don't know if the problem is a bad password , but even so , it should be showing me a error message (i used catch nd try ...)

### > the code !

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Connexion As New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=stockage;User Id=pma;Password=pmapass;")

    Try

        Connexion.Open()

        Dim Requete As String = "UPDATE client SET nom_client ='client unknown' WHERE nom_client is null"
        Dim Commande As New SqlCommand(Requete, Connexion)

        Try
            Console.WriteLine("there was " & Commande.ExecuteNonQuery() & " lignes changed")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Commande.Dispose()
        Connexion.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

### End Module

(when executing the console it shows nothing )
thanks !

Comment: When you debug this, where does it fail?

Comment: it shows nothing ,just the cursor nd a blank console when i tested putting a msg before connexion.open() it shows me just the msg nd nothing else , when i put the msg after connexion.open() it doesn't show anything .

Comment: That's what debugging is for.  Step through the code in a debugger and find out exactly what's going on.

Comment: yeah i tried to debug it , it gives me an error related to the network , while trying to establish the connection to the sql server ," server can't be found or not accessible ,make sure the name of instance is correcte ,nd the sql server is configure to authorize connections ,- can't open the connectio to the server - " :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you're not managing a `SQL` Database with `phpMyAdmin`. `phpMyAdmin` manages `mySQL` databases instead.

Secondly you need to install `Connector/Net` through [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

> Note : **Please go for version 6.6.7** as they have removed Visual
>   Studio integration from 6.7.7 and above

Once the connector is installed, start a new project in VB.NET (Im using 2008) and you will then need to add a reference to the connector.

Choose "Add Reference" from the Project menu, then select "Browse" and browse to the installation folder where the connector was installed,
choose "MySQL.Data.dll" .

[image: Add Reference window]

---

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient 'Very Important

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Connexion As New MySqlConnection
        Dim db_name As String = "stockage"
        Dim db_host As String = "localhost"
        Dim db_username As String = "pma"
        Dim db_password As String = "pmapass"

        If Not Connexion Is Nothing Then Connexion.Close() 'to close already open connections
        Connexion.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", db_host, db_username, db_password, db_name)

        Try
            Connexion.Open()
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to server " + db_host)

            Dim Commande As MySqlCommand
            Dim Requete As String = "UPDATE client SET nom_client ='client unknown' WHERE nom_client is null"

            Commande = New MySqlCommand(Requete, Connexion)
            Console.WriteLine("there was " & Commande.ExecuteNonQuery() & " lines changed")
            Connexion.Close()
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from server " + db_host)

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & ex.Message)

        Finally
            Connexion.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: yeah , but when i add the "private connexion as New MySqlConnection" it says " statement is not valid in a name space" don't know where the problem is !!

Comment: haha i didn't refresh the page :3 thanks a lot man , i changed some (bizzar) things nd it works :D